# GRUB installation for make USB bootable

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, live-usb

Through following a tutorial to make a bootable Windows USB from Ubuntu 14.10 using PC that use BIOS, I opened terminal and run

```
sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/ihab/windows/boot" /dev/sdb
```

to use GRUB for making USB bootable, I should see if everything is ok

```
Installing for i386-pc platform.  
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

But the actual that I got this message which I couldn`t know what to do then

```
grub-install: warning: Attempting to install GRUB to a disk with multiple partition labels.  This is not supported yet..
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists.
```

This should be following the tutorial [mentioned here](http://onetransistor.blogspot.com/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 2):

If this is still an issue, I came across this today and figured out how to solve it. Apparently there's an issue with changing from a gpt to a msdos partition table. If you zero out the beginning of the drive, where `sdb` identifies your drive in `/dev`

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=100
```

And then start from the beginning of the tutorial you mentioned.

Comment: Only correct for BIOS/MBR partitioning. Otherwise you will erase part of gpt as it starts right after protective MBR. If using gpt, with BIOS you must have a 1MB bios_grub partition. Or with UEFI an ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: @oldfred While I'm assuming you're correct, in the tutorial linked to by the OP the `grub-install` command is only executed if using BIOS/MBR. In the section on UEFI it doesn't mention installing grub.